# How to create a package to upload to Hackage?

Tags: haskell, cabal, hackage

How do I generate the appropriate package file?

The hackage upload page has a link to: https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/installing-packages.html#setup-sdist but after reading that I'm still unsure.

I've tried:

```
cabal setup sdist
cabal: unrecognised command: setup (try --help)
```

As well as:

```
setup sdist
zsh: command not found: setup
```

Comment: Do you mean, the `yourproject.cabal` file (you must have that in order for cabal to do anything at all with your project!) or the `yourpackage-0.1.0.0.tar.gz` tarball that can be uploaded to Hackage?

Comment: The `yourpackage-0.1.0.0.tar.gz` tarball.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for `cabal sdist`? Seems as if `setup` in the documentation is overloaded and refers to either `cabal` or `runhaskell ./Setup.hs` https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/installing-packages.html#building-and-installing-packages

Comment: Here is a useful guide: https://functor.tokyo/blog/2018-07-16-release-haskell-packages-to-hackage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate the package:

- With cabal: `cabal sdist`
- With stack: `stack sdist`

Thanks to @ppb